# Adding new documents in single request in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to add new documents in firestore in a operation? I've gone through the documentation under transaction and batch processes, but i think its not possible to perform that job, which include update, set and delete set of operations. Please help, if its possible or if there is any alternative approach to accomplish the task.

This is what firebase documentation has to say under **batched writes**: If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of **set(), update(), or delete()** operations. A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

So **batched writes** doesn't have add operation to add new documents in collection, i can use set operation but for that i need document id.

So lets say if i have this dummy data:

```
var someData = [
            {
                name: "Data1",
                class: "success"
            },
            {
                name: "Data2",
                class: "warning"
            },
            {
                name: "Data3",
                class: "info"
            },
            {
                name: "Data4",
                class: "success"
            }, 
            {
                name: "Data5",
                class: "success"
            },
            {
                name: "Data6",
                class: "warning"
            }, 
            {
                name: "Data7",
                class: "warning"
            },
            {
                name: "Data8",
                class: "info"
            }
        ];
```

and i want to add each object in array as documents(8 documents) with automatically generated document id using **atomic operations** provided by firestore, how to do it?

Comment: Did you read this one? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: yes i've, not useful.

Comment: Can you explain what is not useful about it? Or what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Using a `batch` is the correct solution. If you can't get it to work, please update your question to show what you have, what it does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: @KapilKushwaha: you're saying "a single request", which unfortunately is a rather broad term. Adding multiple documents in one operation (where either all of the documents are added, or none of them are) can be accomplished with batches as others have said. If that doesn't work for you, please edit your question to show what you've tried. If it does work but doesn't allow your use-case, please update your question to explain your use-case a bit more.

Comment: Ok, resolved the issue successfully,under this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data.